# Can't import module from another file [VScode/PySide]

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, path, pyside

noobie here.

I just started looking into PySide ([this tut](https://youtu.be/uzqDnB44qf4?list=PLl1beluPSLsT4XGtS3YDkOEth_FeqTwPv&t=2250)) and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error

```
PS F:\VScode> cd f:/VScode/Pyside6_Sample_Application/Application_Login
PS F:\VScode\Pyside6_Sample_Application\Application_Login> & C:/Users/Blood/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe f:/VScode/Pyside6_Sample_Application/Application_Login/login.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\VScode\Pyside6_Sample_Application\Application_Login\login.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Application_Login.UI.login_window import Ui_w_LoginForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Application_Login'
PS F:\VScode\Pyside6_Sample_Application\Application_Login>
```

problematic line looks like this

```
from Application_Login.UI.login_window import Ui_w_LoginForm
```

file tree is the same as in this
[repo](https://github.com/ermBlood/Pyside6_Sample_Application/blob/master/Application_Login/login.py)

Thx for your roasting :)

I tried convert it to relative path, PySide6 installed, python ver. 3.12

Comment: did you run `pip install pyside6`?

Comment: For sure


"Requirement already satisfied: PySide6"

Comment: your python version is 3.12 right? Please include that in your question. We need as much information as possible for anyone to help. Also not sure why you edited your comment, that's how I was able to spot your python version.

Comment: Yes, 3.12, and because without formatting its total mess

Comment: This has got nothing to do with PySide. If you execute `print(sys.path)` you will see that the module doesn't reside in any of the listed locations. You should always start an application from a script in the parent directory of the root package, as Python will always automatically add that directory to the beginning of `sys.path`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I tried move login.py and __init__.py to same folder(UI), edited path in file and it works.